# How to create the input file for wordcount program mapreduce

Tags: bigdata

What its mean?

```
/user/joe/wordcount/input - input directory in HDFS
/user/joe/wordcount/output - output directory in HDFS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
you can submit the Mapreduce application jar to cluster by below command.

hadoop jar  yourapplication.jar  driver-class input-path(hdfs path) output-path(hdfs path)

First create a simple text file with some content,and copy that file to hdfs  by below command.

hadoop fs -put  your-local-path/input   hdfs-path/

/user/joe/wordcount/input  -- is input file on hdfs .

/user/joe/wordcount/output --  output directory for storing MR result.

in your case you can run like this

hadoop jar  yourapplication.jar  driver-class /user/joe/wordcount/input.txt  
 /user/joe/wordcount/output
```

Comment: thank you its working fine also I got the outpu

Comment: please accept the answer,if it is usefull.